# How can i create custom listview of dates and times in Flutter?

Tags: datetime, listview, button, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using Flutter to develop a to-do app, and inside the "new task" screen i want to create a "reminder" button that displays two custom listviews of seemingly infinite dates and times which the user will be able to select from. What is the best way to create that button?

[image: This is what the display should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker 
and set date formate to what you need

code snippet

```
DateTimePickerWidget(
                minDateTime: DateTime.parse(MIN_DATETIME),
                maxDateTime: DateTime.parse(MAX_DATETIME),
                initDateTime: DateTime.parse(INIT_DATETIME),
                locale: DateTimePickerLocale.pt_br,
                dateFormat: DATE_FORMAT,
                pickerTheme: DateTimePickerTheme(
                  showTitle: false,
                  title: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 40.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text('Date Time Picker Title'),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFFc0ca33)),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf0f4c3),
                ),
                onChange: (dateTime, selectedIndex) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dateTime = dateTime;
                  });
                },
              )
```

working demo , device Language is `Portuguese (PT) Brazil`

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cupertino_date_picker/flutter_cupertino_date_picker.dart';

///
/// @author dylan wu
/// @since 2019-05-10
class DateTimePickerInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DateTimePickerInPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _DateTimePickerInPageState();
}

const String MIN_DATETIME = '2019-05-15 20:10:55';
const String MAX_DATETIME = '2019-07-01 12:30:40';
const String INIT_DATETIME = '2019-05-16 09:00:58';
const String DATE_FORMAT = 'MMMM-EEEE-dd,HH:mm';

class _DateTimePickerInPageState extends State<DateTimePickerInPage> {
  DateTime _dateTime;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dateTime = DateTime.parse(INIT_DATETIME);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle hintTextStyle =
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead.apply(color: Color(0xFF999999));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("DateTimePicker In Page")),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            // min datetime hint
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 115.0,
                    child: Text('min DateTime:', style: hintTextStyle),
                  ),
                  Text(MIN_DATETIME,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // max datetime hint
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 115.0,
                    child: Text('max DateTime:', style: hintTextStyle),
                  ),
                  Text(MAX_DATETIME,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // init datetime hint
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 115.0,
                    child: Text('init DateTime:', style: hintTextStyle),
                  ),
                  Text(INIT_DATETIME,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // date format
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 115.0,
                    child: Text('Date Format:', style: hintTextStyle),
                  ),
                  Text(DATE_FORMAT, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // show custom title widget
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('show custom title', style: hintTextStyle),
                Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (value) {}),
              ],
            ),

            // custom title height
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: Text('custom title height:', style: hintTextStyle),
                  ),
                  Text('40.0', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // date time picker widget
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 40.0),
              child: DateTimePickerWidget(
                minDateTime: DateTime.parse(MIN_DATETIME),
                maxDateTime: DateTime.parse(MAX_DATETIME),
                initDateTime: DateTime.parse(INIT_DATETIME),
                locale: DateTimePickerLocale.pt_br,
                dateFormat: DATE_FORMAT,
                pickerTheme: DateTimePickerTheme(
                  showTitle: false,
                  title: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 40.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text('Date Time Picker Title'),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFFc0ca33)),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf0f4c3),
                ),
                onChange: (dateTime, selectedIndex) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dateTime = dateTime;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),

            // selected date time
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Selected DateTime:',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                  child: Text(
                    _dateTime != null
                        ? '${_dateTime.year}-${_dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${_dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${_dateTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${_dateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${_dateTime.second.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
                        : '',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DateTimePickerInPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, that was very helpful!